# Drop-down menu appears behind slider for short time

Tags: css

This is interesting....Only on chrome.

I have drop-down menu, on hover it appears behind slider, but after ~0,5 seconds it displays like it should be. I got something like delay. Other confusing thing is that i have another dropdown, which use same css markup. But everything is fine with that menu....

```
nav ul .sub-menu {
height: auto; 
width: 100px; 
padding: 20px 15px 5px 15px; 
display: none;
position: absolute; 
top: 21px; 
left: -25px; 
z-index: 999; 
background-color: #000; 
border: 1px solid rgb(230, 178, 58);}


nav ul .sub-menu.visible { display: block; }
```

Comment: If the css markup is the same then something must be different in the html.  Can you show us the relevant pieces of that?

Comment: also html is the same, i changed only li names. As i mentioned, problem appears only on chrome... im sure that , menu is interfering with js slider...

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle.